# how to deploy liquibase changes with grails 2.5

Tags: grails, war, liquibase

Grails puts the liquibase xml script files in the following location in the war:

WEB-INF/classes/migrations/

There are at least 5 strategies to get these changes onto the prodcution server, but none of them are viable:

1. set "grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStart = true".  This does not work as grails database migration plugin is hard coded to liquibase 2.0.5, which is full of bugs and is unusable.  it creates a broken schema.
2. put the liquibase 3.3.5 jar on production server, then try to run it, pointing it to the war file to get the changelog files. This simply does not work. see ["Unexpected error running Liquibase: Unknown Reason" liquibase 3.3.5 and grails war file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32479875/unexpected-error-running-liquibase-unknown-reason-liquibase-3-3-5-and-grails)
3. unpack the war, and run the liquibase command line against the unpacked changelog files. This is not possible in our case, as the jar command is not available on the production servers, and we cant add it.
4. deploy the war, which unpacks it, then run liquibase command line against the resultant files. This is the only solution we have found so far, but this has one major problem: as soon as you deploy the new war, it runs the app, without first updating the database, so users get crashes.
5. Some other solution?

Unfortunately, we cant find a way to get grails to produce two artifacts, the war and a separate file (e.g. a tar or zip) with just the liquibase files in it.

We don't have the benefit of continuous build servers or pupet scripts or similar, we just want to build and deploy simple applications as wars. Liquibase is a major hurdle to this, at least for grails 2.5 apps which are somewhat crippled with liquibase 2.0.5 bundled with them by default.

We could resort to hand copying the migrations directory, zipping it and supplying it along side the war to the customer, but it would be very easy to get these out of sync.

We have no spare servers or budget for automation or tools, unfortunately.

Any ideas or strategies?

Comment: I currently use `grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStart = true` without issue. Specify exactly what issues you are facing with it

Comment: We used to use that, but it fails to correctly set auto-increment values with mysql 5.6.  when we switched to using liquibase 3.3.5 on the command line, it worked.  Apparently this is one of many bugs in liquibase 2.0.5.